# ipv6 and TidHTTP issue on Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, ipv6

we are trying to connect to an ipv6 local server address. This is the code snippet

```
_st := IdHTTP1.Get('http://[fe80::a6ee:57ff:fe5c:7de6]:8000/reparti');
```

The issue is the following:

- If we compile for Windows -> It works and we get the json response
- if we compile for either Android or iOS -> we get

  > "socket error #22 invalid argument"

  and no response and the server do not receive any request

What are we missing?

Thank you for the support

Comment: What version of RAD and Indy are you using?

Comment: You are using an IPv6 protocol... If you are using a SmartPhone can be incompatible.

Comment: There is a lot of processing going on inside of `TIdHTTP.Get()`. What does the call stack look like when the error happens?

Answer (score 1):

The IP address you are attempting to connect to is incomplete. It is missing the mandatory scope ID.

Comment: we have tried with several scope ID without success

Comment: @LucaAnniciello You need to use the _correct_ scope ID. Don't just try random things.

Comment: It is my understanding that in http addresses we do not need the scopeid to be specified

Comment: @LucaAnniciello IPv6 link-local addresses _always_ require the scope ID. It's part of the address.

Comment: Thank you Michael, the only way I was able to have it working in ipv6 was to assign to our cloud server a DNS. Now the issue with the local address still remains open. In fact i have been using the correct scope id but both on android an MacOS I gave no joy and still I get the same socket error. I'm able to ping from both machine the server local ipv6 address on the correct scope ID

Comment: After a bit of searching it seems that Indy do not support yet the scopeID!